# How to go about combining two objects, manipulate the data, then separate them?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two classes with some similar fields, some different, and a form that utilizes two different objects depending on what mode it's in (insert/edit).

Instead of using two different objects and if statements checking the form mode, I'd like to have one struct to be hydrated with either of the two objects fields so I can manipulate one object through the page life-cycle. Then separated the struct back to its respective object for insert/updating the DB.

Example of classes:

```
public partial class SomeClass
{
  public Int32 B {get;set;}
  public String C {get;set;}
  public Boolean D {get;set;}
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
  public Int32 A {get;set;}
  public Int32 B {get;set;}
  public String C {get;set;}  
}
```

Update with Solution Example:

```
public interface IInsertable
{
    string SharedName { get; set; }
    string SharedID { get; set; }
    string editedFieldValue { get; set; }
    long GetSuperSecreteInfo();
}

internal class InsertableImplementation : IInsertable
{
    public string SharedName { get; set; }
    public string SharedID { get; set; }
    public string editedFieldValue { get; set; }

    public long GetSuperSecreteInfo()
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

public interface IUpdateable
{
    string SharedName { get; set; }
    string SharedID { get; set; }
    string updatedFieldValue { get; set; }
    Guid GenerateStevesMagicGuid();
}

internal class UpdateableImplementation : IUpdateable
{
    public string SharedName { get; set; }
    public string SharedID { get; set; }
    public string updatedFieldValue { get; set; }

    public Guid GenerateStevesMagicGuid()
    {
        return new Guid();
    }
}

public static class WonderTwinFactory
{
    public static WonderTwins GenerateWonderTwin(IUpdateable updateable, IInsertable insertable)
    {
        var wt = new WonderTwins();

        // who will win? 
        wt.SharedID = updateable.SharedID;
        wt.SharedID = insertable.SharedID;

        // you decide? 
        wt.SharedName = updateable.SharedName;

        wt.editedFieldValue = "stuff";

        return wt;
    }
}

public class WonderTwins : IInsertable, IUpdateable
{
    public string SharedName { get; set; }
    public string SharedID { get; set; }
    public string editedFieldValue { get; set; }

    public long GetSuperSecreteInfo()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public string updatedFieldValue { get; set; }

    public Guid GenerateStevesMagicGuid()
    {
        return new Guid();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUpdateable updateable = new UpdateableImplementation();
        IInsertable insertable = new InsertableImplementation();

        WonderTwins dualImplementatin = WonderTwinFactory.GenerateWonderTwin(updateable, insertable);

        IUpdateable newUpdateable = dualImplementatin as IUpdateable;
        IInsertable newInsertable = dualImplementatin as IInsertable;


    }
}
```

Comment: A is only in SomeOtherClass and D is only in SomeClass

Comment: Sorry, I misread. The classes need to be combined so that A - D can be read or set through one object, then separated back to their respective classes for CRUD operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have both classes implement an interface that defines the operations common to each, including both the fields that are shared (assuming the view needs to access them) and also a method to actually perform the operation that they represent (insert/edit).

Comment: I ended up having to make an Interface for the two classes, an additional factory class which implemented both interfaces and a final class to wrap up an object to send to the browser. Thanks a ton because I haven't written an interface before so this definitely has given me some extra experience.

Answer (score 0):

Other way of doing such things is using C# dynamic object and assign properties directly. It may help to avoid any new type or interface and directly utilizing new dynamic object any time, as much as required.

```
var newObject = new {
objectOfClass1 = x.prop1,
objectOfClass2 = x.prop2
}
```